# Find Trello cards by number

Tags: trello

Is there any way to find Trello cards by their ID (or card number, I'm not sure what it's called)?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've found that you can simply enter the card number (for instance '12') in the search box, like this:
[image]

When you hit enter (or click the search button), your card number 12 of the current board will be immediately opened.
Actually, that's a great experience.

Unfortunately, searching for the card in the 'Search and Filter Cards' option won't return any results, and sometimes that can be confusing.

**UPDATE:** it seems that 'Search and Filter Cards' option should work as well (as Bobby pointed in [his answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/28440/17044)), but for some strange reason, it isn't working for me.

Comment: > searching for the card in the 'Search and Filter Cards' option won't return any results <- that's the part that made me search for the answer, so that's something Fog Creek might look to fix/remedy

Comment: Does searching for a card by number still work for you?  It doesn't seem to work for me as of Feb. 2015 using either "#905" or just "905".

Comment: You're right, this doesn't work anymore. Now the solution below proposed by @Bobby Grace is the right one.

Comment: confirming as of May 2018 - both this answer from @NelsonReis and Bobby-grace no longer works -

Comment: Confirming as of April 2020 - both this answer from @NelsonReis and Bobby-grace still no longer works :(.

Answer (score 4):

You can filter cards by their card number. Just click 'Search and Filter Cards' in the board sidebar and add the number.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I've just tried to filter my #12 card above, and the Trello search retrieved no cards.

Comment: did you filter by '12' or '#12'. I've found you need to include the '#' for it to pull up by card number

Comment: @Jess, both options (with or without '#') didn't worked out for me. Meanwhile, I've found a great way to do it, as you can see in my own answer below.

Comment: @NelsonReis If that's not working, it must be a bug. Could you send a link to the board to support@trello.com? We'll see what's up.

Comment: @BobbyGrace, I've just sent the email (Case FC2313426). Thanks.

Comment: @NelsonReis Replied! Let me know if it works or what you're seeing.

Comment: I know it's been 4 years... but this no longer works. Is there a current method for retrieving a card by its card number?

Comment: this doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

I made a rookie mistake searching for ticket 6 which wouldn't work, tried #6 still no good, but then searched for 06 and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I found that entering the card number in the search, in the menu located on the right side, will only return the card with that number.

[image: e.g.]

Answer (score 0):

You will have to click on "Filter" Option within a specific Trello board rather than the global Search Option and then search for the ID wrapped around with double quotes.
Example: "66", this will highlight only the card with ID: 66 on the main panel while filtering out everything else.

Though it's a very old question, I'm putting my answer here as there is a change in the interface and the way you search than the accepted answer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Yes, 01 works instead of 1 only for search. Also, FYI, if you would like to search for ticket no 12, then you simply enter 12, no need to add zero here.